# Parse a csv file and create a dictionary of partial results

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv

I have a bunch of .csv files which I have to read and look for data. The .csv file is of the format:

> ```
> A row of data I will ignore
> State,County,City
> WA,king,seattle
> WA,pierce,tacoma
> ```

In every csv file, the order of columns is not consistent. For example in csv1 the order can be State,County,City, in csv2 it can be City,County,State. What I am interested is the State and County. Given a county I want to find out what State it is in. I am ignoring the fact that same counties can exist in multiple States. The way I am approaching this:

```python
with open(‘file.csv’) as f:
    data = f.read()

# convert the data to iterable, skip the first line
reader = csv.DictReader(data.splitlines(1)[1:])
lines = list(reader)
counties = {k: v for (k,v in ((line[‘county’], line[‘State’]) for line in lines)}
```

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, using a `with` block to open the file and `csv.DictReader()` to parse it.

Your list handling is a bit clumsy, though.  To skip a line, use `next(f)`.  Avoid making a list of the entire file's data, if you can process the file line by line.  The dict comprehension has an unnecessary complication as well.

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    _ = next(f)
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    counties = { line['County']: line['State'] for line in reader }
```

Your sample file had `County` as the header, whereas your code looked for `line[‘county’]`.  I assume that the curly quotes are an artifact of copy-pasting, but you should pay attention to the capitalization.

Comment: I am really getting the data from an S3 bucket, but I didn't want to make the code more complicated in my example. So, I get the key from the bucket and then I say

    data = key.get_contents_as_string()

So I am not really reading from a file. Instead, the contents of the key are the string representation of the csv file. 

I like the way you eliminated the list and cleaned up the dict comprehension, is there a way that I can avoid doing the data.splitlines(1)[1:]) when I create the reader since I already have the data in a string? (and i need to ignore the first row)